# The new version of my iOS app appears in the App Store but users are unable to update their current version to the new one

Tags: ios, app-store

I have had an app in the App Store for 1 month now and I just released a new version yesterday.

Now, new users who download the app from the App Store gets the new version, which is great, but people who already had the app can't update it. If they go to the App Store and look for the app, they'll see an "Open" button instead of an "Update" button.

Is it something usual when a new version was just released, so it would just be a matter of time before the update is available ?

Comment: I hope new version will take some to reflect in All App Store. Please confirm in same store you can't see the updated version where a new version is downloaded?

Comment: When was the update went live? Also check the availability section in app.

Comment: Everything seems fine now, after 3 days.

Answer (score 0):

It was a matter of time indeed.

After 2 days, users were able to update the app from the App Store.